# Is it possible getting id's from one project to another by using Test Runner

Tags: soapui

I have 2 projects.I am running these projects one by one by using Test Runner(Project Level).Is there any way passing id's from Project1 to Project2.

Thanks,
Arivazhagan

Comment: What is that making you to `pass values across the projects`? In general, each test should be independent.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.Project.setPropertyValue("name",value)
```

and get those from a different project

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.Project.Workspace.getProjectByName("projectname").getPropertyValue("name")
```

Answer (score 0):

The command line testrunner is able to load only one project at a time. You have two options:

1. Reformat your "projects" into separate test suites under one project. You can then pass information between the different test suites.
2. You can write any information from one project out to a file (SoapUI-Pro has a data dump step, or use custom Groovy step to write out the data), and have your second project read in that file in.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of global properties to achieve this.

To Set Global Property:

```
com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.PropertyExpansionUtils.globalProperties.setPropertyValue('propertyName', 'propertyValue')
```

To Access Global Property:

```
com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.PropertyExpansionUtils.getGlobalProperty('propertyName')
```

Comment: Hi Ramu, I don't how how to set this Global Property in praticaL,can you help me ?

Comment: Hi, use the first line of code in groovy script or script assertion in Project1, where you are capturing/generating the id (the value you want to pass b/w projects) .    Use the second line of code in Project2 from Groovy script or scrip assertion where you want to access the value (id)

Comment: I tried all the above mentioned answers, it works fine when i run groovy script manually for setting global property "com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.PropertyExpansionUtils.globalProperties.setPropertyValue('propertyName', 'propertyValue')
" and i can see the global property is Set in preferences. But if the grrovy script is run as a step when running whole project(by using test runner), the global property is not updated and not set and i dont see the new value in preferences. Can any1 help me in this ? Thanks

Comment: You do write properties from Project1 into a file and then read that file from Project2. Hope it helps you.